# Flutter grid layout

Tags: flutter, forms, web, grid

I am developing an Web/Android/iOS app with Flutter and I'm having difficulties creating a simple form where elements are aligned in a grid. Something like Bootstrap with HTML.

[image: grid layout]

I tried creating a grid like this with GridView widget - but elements cannot have fixed height, it's all about childAspectRatio so that's no good.

I also tried using Wrap widget but I have to calculate width of children which isn't ideal.

What am I missing, this shouldn't be this hard, right?

Comment: number of elements are fixed?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yes, its a Form.

Comment: did you try with column-row?

Comment: you can try flutter super grid https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_super_grid